# How to get List of ColumnNames by part of name?

Tags: excel, powerquery

How to get list of unknown count of ColumnNames by known part of name in Excel power query?
There is example Table

```
src_columns = Table.ColumnNames(
    Table.FromRecords({
        [Name = "Bob", Question = "qwe1", "Reply_1" = "rep1", "Reply_2" = "rep11", <unknown count of replies>],
        [Name = "Jim", Question = "qwe2", "Reply_1" = "rep2", "Reply_2" = "rep22", <unknown count of replies>],
        [Name = "Paul", Question = "qwe3", "Reply_1" = "rep3", "Reply_2" = "rep33", <unknown count of replies>],
        [Name = "Ringo", Question = "qwe4", "Reply_1" = "rep4", "Reply_2" = "rep44", <unknown count of replies>]
    })
)
```

I need something like "Select ColumnNames from src_columns where columnname like 'Reply%'"

Answer (score 0):

I found answer, please close question.
I was searching List.FindText
List.FindText(colnames, "Reply")